# Harford 2023 model: explicit reference

Tags: nlp, language-model, reference-request

I'm citing in a paper the Wizard-Vicuna Uncensored 30B model of Hartford (2023). But I don't have an exact bib reference other than various web links for that model. Could anyone help?